# How could we see the cell numbers in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, line-numbers

Just wondering is there a way of displaying the cell numbers as a reference in Jupyter notebook?

I saw the great answers on how to show line numbers within a cell? However, if we have a long piece of notebook, is there a way to show the cell numbers on the far left? That way, it would be easier to reference when you working with you teams.

Really appreciate your help! New to python & jupyter. Apologize if this question sounds silly.

Cheers